# Very long autocorrelation with low Augmented Dick Fuller test result

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have daily a time series that after being first order differenced, has the ACF sinusoidal and that decays very slowly (more than 50 periods) and with a PACF, also oscillating, with very high values for the first 10 periods and above the 90% line. That would indicate a non-stationary series, but the Augmented Dick Fuller test is giving

```
Test Statistic        -11.116
p-value                 0.000
Lags                   25.000
Number of Obs        1700.000
Critical Value 1%      -3.434
Critical Value 5%      -2.863
Critical Value 10%     -2.568
```

So it seems that the series is stationary. How can this be?

Comment: It is called Dickey-Fuller test and it looks for a unit root to the characteristic polynomial. The augmented test applies to a series that is already differenced.

Comment: Can you give us more background? For example, if you difference a stationary series, you will induce long memory via a unit root, but the root is -1 rather than 1, which is why the ADF test does not find it. Try `T=1e3; set.seed(1); x=rnorm(T); y=x; for(t in 2:T) y[t]=-0.75*y[t-1]+x[t]; 
acf(diff(y))` in R: this is a stationary AR(1) process that, when differenced, shows oscilating, significant ACF for the first 12 periods.

Comment: Did my example help?